# How to access store context within a plugin in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to add third party code and use it in my Nuxt app. Basically I wrote a plugin under `@/plugins/vendorCode/logFn.js` which contains a dumb function :

```
export default ({ store }) => {
    console.log('store is', store)
}
```

As you can see I try to access store and perform later some mutation. That's my next step.
But for now I'm stuck.

In my Vue Component, I've a button calling the logFn, here's what I did :

```
<script>
import logFn from '@/plugins/vendorCode/logFn.js'

  export default {
    methods: {
      onClick () {
        logFn()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

So far so good. Once page reload, I can see the result of my logFn in the console, with the store object.

**First question : why it is print now ? I did not call it at all.**

Then I click the button and got an error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined`.

**Second question : why this error regarding the log I had previously?**

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question : why it is print now ? I did not call it at all.**

Because Nuxt calls it for you.
Nuxt calls every .js files inside ./plugins folder, before instantiating the root vue.js application.
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins

If you want to use `logFn.js` as a utility function or something, you should put it in ./assets or create your own util folder.

**Second question : why this error regarding the log I had previously?**

Because you didn't pass the required argument.
The cause could be much easier to locate, if written like below.

Your code equals to:

```
export default function (context) {
    console.log('store is', context.store)
}
```

The function needs an argument.
When the Nuxt calls it, Nuxt gives it [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context), so you can access [store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/).

When you called that function in your page, you didn't pass an required argument, so that error occurred.

**So what should you do ?**

Create `~/assets/js/logFn.js`.

```
export default (store) => { // <- not { store }, but store
    console.log('store is', store)
}
```

Call it like this, in your `page.vue`

```
<script>
import logFn from '~/assets/js/logFn.js'

  export default {
    methods: {
      onClick () {
        logFn(this.$store)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: it works, I did this at first but thought it was bit odd to pass store like this. Thank you for your help sosmii